# Powershell Where-Object -in clause

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to delete some orphaned folders. I have a list of folder names that are orphaned, and I am attempting to find the corresponding File object. Unfortuantely, I can't seem to get the `-in` clause to work as I would expect.

A slightly contrived example:

```
$orphans = ls | select Name
ls | ?{$_.Name -in $orphans}
ls -Include $orphans
```

No files are returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for this to work you need to do

```
$orphans = ls | select -ExpandProperty Name
```

Or inside the `Where-Clause`

```
ls | ?{$_.Name -in $orphans.name}
```

`$orphans` in your code is an object array with a name property. Break that property out into a simple string array and you should get the results you expect.

I will also assume that the code sample is just that... a sample. That code, once working correctly, seems redundant.

**Powershell v2**

The above code didn't work on Powershell v2. A combination of `-ExpandProperty` and `-contains` seemed to correct the issue:

```
$orphans = ls | select -ExpandProperty Name
ls | ?{$orphans -contains $_.Name}
```

Comment: Yes, definitely an example, I left out the 10 lines that compare DB results to folder structure. I swear I tried ExpandProperty... thanks.

Comment: @Kavius We all make silly mistakes. Best way to learn! I know.

Comment: I updated the example to take into account some PSv2 differences when I moved the script to the deployment machine.